# How do I delete only one row of appended information in a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a "My Favorite Movies" list page where users can add and rate movies. This program should include:

1) a form where you can add to the list and rate it

2) a table of all the things you've added

3) delete button for each row of the table that lets you remove elements from the list **(what i'm having trouble on)**

**Instead of deleting only one row, it deletes every appended movie/rating in the table. Also if you click anywhere else, it deletes everything as well.**

*4) bonus: sort feature, so i can sort entries in the table by the their title or their rating.*

example here: [rithm school example](https://www.rithmschool.com/courses/intermediate-javascript-part-2/jquery-intermediate-exercises)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addMovieButton').click(function() {
    var addToTitle = $('#title').val();
    $('#tableTitle').append('<tr><td>' + addToTitle + '</td></tr>');

    var addToRating = $("#rating").val();
    $('#tableRating').append('<tr><td>' + addToRating + '</td></tr>');

    $('#tableDelete').append('<tr><td><input type="button" value="Delete All"</tr></td>');

    $('#tableRow').on('click', function() {
      $('#tableTitle').last().children().remove();
      $('#tableRating').last().children().remove();
      $('#tableDelete').last().children().remove();


    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

th {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label><b>Title</b></label>
  <input id="title" type="text" value="Movie Title">

  <label><b>Rating</b></label>
  <input id="rating" type="text" value="Rate The Movie from 0 to 10">

  <button type='button' id="addMovieButton">Add Movie</button>
</form>

<table>
  <tr id="tableRow">
    <th id="tableTitle">Title</th>
    <th id="tableRating">Rating</th>
    <th id="tableDelete">Delete</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#tableTitle').last()` - IDs must be unique within the document `$("#tableTitle")` will *not* find all of the elements with ID tableTitle.  Use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: When you use `input` tags to write some text in it yourself, use the attribute `placeholder=""` which will do what you need without having the user needing to delete the text before typing his information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've put all titles in a parent, and all rating in another parent ,and all delete buttons in another one . you should place the information about each row in a parent and then you can delete by row easily.
(also you can add td,tbody it's just sample to showing the way)

```js
$('#addMovieButton').click(function () {
                var addToTitle = $('#title').val();
                var addToRating = $("#rating").val();
                $('#table').append('<tr><th>' + addToTitle + '</th><th>' + addToRating + '</th><th><input type="button" value="Delete All" class="tableDelete"></th></tr>');


                $('.tableDelete').click(function () {
                    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                    
                });

            });
```

```css
        h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

th {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form>
        <label><b>Title</b></label>
        <input id="title" type="text" value="Movie Title">

        <label><b>Rating</b></label>
        <input id="rating" type="text" value="Rate The Movie from 0 to 10">

        <button type='button' id="addMovieButton">Add Movie</button>
    </form>

    <table id="table">
       
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks a ton! now I just have to figure out how to sort.

Answer (score 1):

### `<table>` Structure

The structure of the appended "row" are not valid HTML. A `<table>` will have at least one `<tbody>`. If the user doesn't add it the browser will. Although most methods, function, and properties will treat the `<table>` as the direct parent of `<tr>`, there are some advantages to targeting `<tbody>` instead. If there's a `<thead>` then targeting the `<tbody>` can free you from extra steps trying to avoid the `<th>`.

Keep these rules in mind when structuring a `<table>`

- `<tbody>` can only have `<tr>` as children (direct descendants)
- `<tr>` can only have `<td>` and `<th>` as children
- `<td>` and `<th>` can have anything as descendants.

Make sure rows are structured like so:

```
<tr><td</td>...<td></td></tr>
```

Add row to `<table>` or `<tbody>`

---

#### Demo

The following demo has detailed comments within the HTML, and CSS, as well as step by step details commented in the JavaScript

```js
$(function() {

  /*
  Bind the <form> to the 'submit', 'click', and 'change' events.
  Pass the Event Object thru
  */
  $('form').on('submit click change', function(event) {

    // Reference the type of event
    let eType = event.type;

    // if the 'submit' event was triggered...
    if (eType === 'submit') {

      // Stop the <form> from sending data to a server and resetting
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get the values of the <input>
      let name = $('.title').val();
      let rate = $('.rating').val();

      // Declare a htmlString using a Template Literal 
      const row = `
        <tr><td>${name}</td>
        <td>${rate}</td>
        <td><input class='sel' type='checkbox'>
        </td></tr>`;

      // Render the htmlString as the last child of the <tbody>
      $('.data').append(row);

      // Reset <form>
      $(this).trigger('reset');

      // ...otherwise if the 'click' event triggered...
    } else if (eType === 'click') {

      // ...and the clicked tag has class 'del'...
      if ($(event.target).hasClass('del')) {

        /*
        Collect all checked <input class='sel'>
        then on .each() one...
        */
        $('.sel:checked').each(function(i) {

          /*
          Get the ancestor <tr> of the current .sel
          and remove it
          */
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        // Reset the <form>
        $('form').trigger('reset');
      }
      
      // ...otherwise if the 'change' event was triggered...
    } else if (eType === 'change') {

      // ...and the changed tag id is 'all'...
      if (event.target.id === 'all') {

        // Check if #all is checked or not
        let allChk = $('#all').is(':checked');

        // Loop thru each() <input class='sel'>...
        $('.sel').each(function(i) {

          /* 
          and check current .sel if #all is checked
          or uncheck current .sel if #all is NOT checked
          */
          $(this).prop('checked', allChk);
        });
      }
    }
    // Stop any events from bubbling any further up the event chain
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Arial;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 12px auto
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

th {
  height: 30px;
  width: 20%;
}

th:first-of-type {
  width: 60%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

button,
input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}

.all {
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border: 1.5px inset rgba(0, 28, 255, 0.3);
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.all::after {
  content: 'Selected'
}

/*
When input@all is :checked the label.all that follows
#all will change 
the content of its pseudo-element from 'Selected' to 'All'
*/
#all:checked+.all::after {
  content: 'All'
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 3px outset rgba(0, 28, 255, 0.4);
  color: rgba(0, 28, 255, 0.6);
}

.all:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 28, 255, 0.8);
  background: rgba(0, 28, 255, 0.2);
}

.rating {
  text-align: right;
  width: 4ch;
}

.title {
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 27ch;
}

/*
The checkbox #all is not visible to user but is accessible through the label.all 
which it is synced with (see comments in HTML
*/
#all {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Title</label>
  <!--
  The [required] attribute enables built-in form validation
  If the submit event is triggered 
  and either <input> is blank, the submit event is interrupted and 
  a tooltip will notify 
  user that the <input> cannot be empty
  -->
  <input class="title" type="text" placeholder="Pulp Fiction" required>

  <label>Rating</label>
  
  <!-- See previous comment -->
  <input class="rating" type="number" min='0' max='10' placeholder="10" required>
  <!--
  <button type='submit'> or <input type='submit'>
  or <button> within a <form> will trigger a submit event by default
  -->
  <button>Add Movie</button>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>
          <button class='del' type='button'>Remove</button>
          <!--
          A <label> and a form control (ie <input>, <textarea>, <select>, etc) can be synced by
          matching the [for] attribute value to the form controls #id:
          1. <label for='XXX'>
          2. <input id='XXX'>
          When synced, clicking one will remotely click the other
          -->
          <input id='all' type='checkbox'>
          <label class='all' for='all'></label></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--
    See post on <table> structure
    -->
    <tbody class='data'></tbody>
  </table>

</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```